# GeoServer Raster WMS Layer update/filter like CQL, ECQL

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, cql-filter, cql

I have added the raster layer from GeoServer as a WMS source.

There is an HTML filter to apply changes with GeoServer Raster WMS Layer, which is not working with RasterSymbolizer, and CQL filter.

Like setFilter for a vector layer with Mapbox GL JS.

SLD:

```
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="10" label="10 min" color="#e7ecff" opacity="0.898039"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="20" label="20 min" color="#e1f8e1"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="30" label="30 min" color="#cff7d3"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="40" label="40 min" color="#a9e2ae" opacity="0.941176"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="50" label="50 min" color="#a5cba7"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="60" label="1 hr" color="#e7d676"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="120" label="2 hrs" color="#f2b276"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="240" label="4 hrs" color="#e77657"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="360" label="6 hrs" color="#be3e40"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="720" label="12 hrs" color="#9b3234"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="960" label="16 hrs" color="#7a2764"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1200" label="20 hrs" color="#531a45"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1400" label="> 1 day" color="#291144"/>
```

I have tried:

1. CQL but I don't know the property value for the raster layer.

```
http://yourserder:8080/geoserver//wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&cql_filter=circle_n=circle name&request=GetMap&layers=rasterlayer:rasterlayer&styles=&bbox=bounding boxof your desire&width=768&height=492&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&
```

2. I have also tried a RasterSymbolizer with the env variable but it also not working.

RasterSymbolizer SLD:

```
<sld:ColorMap name='env'>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="10" label="10 min" color="${env('10_min','#e7ecff')}" opacity="0.898039"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="20" label="20 min" color="${env('20_min','#e1f8e1')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="30" label="30 min" color="${env('30_min','#cff7d3')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="40" label="40 min" color="${env('40_min','#a9e2ae')}" opacity="0.941176"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="50" label="50 min" color="${env('50_min','#a5cba7')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="60" label="1 hr" color="${env('1_hour','#e7d676')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="120" label="2 hrs" color="${env('2_hour','#f2b276')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="240" label="4 hrs" color="${env(4_hour), #e77657}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="360" label="6 hrs" color="${env('6_hour','#be3e40')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="720" label="12 hrs" color="${env('12_hour','#9b3234')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="960" label="16 hrs" color="${env('16_hour','#7a2764')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1200" label="20 hrs" color="${env('20_hour','#531a45')}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1400" label="> 1 day" color="${env('1_day','#291144')}"/>
</sld:ColorMap>
```

`https://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=geo%3Alayer_clim_w&TILED=true&WIDTH=320&HEIGHT=320&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A113&BBOX=0%2C-5009377.085697312%2C5009377.085697311%2C-9.313225746154785e-10&env=10_min:%23000000;20_min:%23000000;30_min:%23000000;40_min:%23000000;50_min:%23000000`

Is there any way to apply changes to the raster layer with GeoServer?

something similar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431982/how-can-i-filter-clip-a-raster-provided-by-wms-geoserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for working CQL filter for raster with a raster symbolizer solution.

Note: GeoServer validation will not pass the SLD but It will work after saving.

Idea is to change the opacity to zero for the slider value.

```xml
<sld:ColorMap name='env'>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="10" label="10 min" color="#e7ecff" opacity="${env('value_0', 1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="20" label="20 min" color="#e1f8e1" opacity="${env('value_1',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="30" label="30 min" color="#cff7d3" opacity="${env('value_2',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="40" label="40 min" color="#a9e2ae" opacity="${env('value_3',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="50" label="50 min" color="#a5cba7" opacity="${env('value_4',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="60" label="1 hr" color="#e7d676" opacity="${env('value_5',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="120" label="2 hrs" color="#f2b276" opacity="${env('value_6',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="240" label="4 hrs" color="#e77657}" opacity="${env('value_7',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="360" label="6 hrs" color="#be3e40" opacity="${env('value_8',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="720" label="12 hrs" color="#9b3234" opacity="${env('value_9',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="960" label="16 hrs" color="#7a2764" opacity="${env('value_10',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1200" label="20 hrs" color="#531a45" opacity="${env('value_11',1)}"/>
<sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1400" label="> 1 day" color="#291144" opacity="${env('value_12',1)}"/>
</sld:ColorMap>
```

Write javascript:

```js
let variable = '';
if (value >= 0 && value <= 10) {
    variable = '';
} else if (value > 20 && value <= 20) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;';
} else if (value > 20 && value <= 30) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;';
} else if (value > 30 && value <= 40) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;';
} else if (value > 40 && value <= 50) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;';
} else if (value > 50 && value <= 60) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;';
} else if (value > 60 && value <= 120) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;';
} else if (value > 120 && value <= 240) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;';
} else if (value > 240 && value <= 360) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;';
} else if (value > 360 && value <= 720) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;value_8:0;';
} else if (value > 720 && value <= 960) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;value_8:0;value_9:0;';
} else if (value > 960 && value <= 1200) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;value_8:0;value_9:0;value_10:0;';
} else if (value > 1200 && value <= 1400) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;value_8:0;value_9:0;value_10:0;value_11:0;';
} else if (value > 1400) {
    variable = 'value_0:0;value_1:0;value_2:0;value_3:0;value_4:0;value_5:0;value_6:0;value_7:0;value_8:0;value_9:0;value_10:0;value_11:0;value_12:0;';
}
```

Apply changes with this URL.

```
https://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=geo%3Alayer_clim_w&TILED=true&WIDTH=320&HEIGHT=320&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A113&BBOX=0%2C-5009377.085697312%2C5009377.085697311%2C-9.313225746154785e-10&env=variable
```

Comment: Geoserver doens't allow to save the incorrect SLD. It gives internal error

Comment: Not true, but the above SLD is working without validation.

Comment: It does not pass for me, latest Geoserer version. I suggested to dynamically create an SLD on server-side using PHP. Leaflet then calls this PHP on SLD param in layer.setParams It perfectly works and answers the question but seems that my answer has been deleted by a moderator. Really don't understand why

Comment: Try to click on save, it will work without validation.